# How to connect to an IP Camera using HttpURLconnection with authentication in Android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, ip-camera, bufferedinputstream

So I have been trying for some time to connect to an IP Camera (Model: Foscam fI9821w v2) through my Android application using HttpURLconnection.

As it says on the Foscam forum the following format for the URL I need to use would be as follows: "http://ipaddress:port/cgibin/CGIProxy.fcgicmd=snapPicture2&usr=admin&pwd=xxx".

The following is a method from my code attempting to connect to the Camera and retreive the stream:

```
public InputStream httpRequest(String link, String usr, String pwd) {
    InputStream is = null;

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(link);
        System.out.println("Attempting to connect to: " + url.toString());

        // basic auth
        String userpass = usr + ":" + pwd;
        int flags = Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP;
        byte[] authEncBytes = userpass.getBytes();
        String authStringEnc = Base64.encodeToString(authEncBytes, flags);

        String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encode(userpass.getBytes(), flags);

        System.out.println("*** basicAuth: " + basicAuth);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        //urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900F Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.105 Mobile Safari/537.36");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic" + basicAuth);

        //urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();
        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == 200) {
            is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        }
        System.out.println("WHAT DOES THIS SAY: " + urlConnection.toString());
        System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + responseCode);

        int rc = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
        if ((rc == 401) || (rc == 403) || (rc == 404) || (rc >= 500)){
            Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(rc));
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "SUCCESS!");
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}
```

I use the URL format as above however I'm assuming I can remove "&usr=admin&pwd=xxx" from the end of the URL as I use setRequestProperty for the authentication? (Correct me if I am wrong). I have tried the URL in another application (iSpy) and it works, but that has "&usr=admin&pwd=xxx" at the end of it.
Anyway, I always get the following error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.15 (port 80) after 5000ms
```

Followed by:

```
java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed
```

I have searched the Internet for quite some time now to try and figure out what I am doing wrong and I have altered my code multiple times. Can anyone help me identify what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: "Correct me if I am wrong" -- that is not something that you can do in general. Whether this particular device supports that conversion, I cannot say.

Comment: It is unclear what is coming into the function - your error seems to indicate that you've not created the URL correctly though I'm not positive about that.    Print out urlConnection.getURL().toString() before trying to call this.  I feel that you do need to add the URL parameters.

Comment: "/192.168.0.15" The error message show a "/" before the IP address

Comment: @stdunbar I have done urlConnection.getURL().toString() and the result is "http://192.168.0.15:80/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=snapPicture2". How would I add the URL parameters correctly?

Comment: Well, right away there is no protocol - i.e. "http://"

Comment: @stdunbar Sorry I'm not sure why but when I comment it, stackoverflow keeps automatically creating a link with it, thus removing the protocol. It does infact have http:// at the start